How to send Google Analytics 4 e-commerce events using @next/third-parties/google package and sendGTMEvent function in Next.js?
We have a Next.js app that uses Pages Router. For the purposes of analytics, we implemented GA4 via GTM. This works fine for basic (and enhanced) tracking, but we need to send specific e-commerce events too, mostly add_to_cart and purchase events.
Next's "third-parties" library exposes some components and functions, and their docs say that, for sending GA4 events, we shouldn't use the "sendGAEvent" function (which also then needs GoogleAnalytics component too, which is not desired when GoogleTagManager component is already used), but instead, if we use Google Tag Manager for GA4 configuration, we should use that. For this the same library has "sendGTMEvent" function, but unlike sendGAEvent that accepts an array of arguments much like gtag function from Google itself, this function excepts Object...
Anyhow, in our _app.js file we initiate the GoogleTagManager:
import {GoogleTagManager} from '@next/third-parties/google';

return <>
  <GoogleTagManager gtmId='GTM-SOME_VALUE' />
</>

Now we need a way to use "sendGTMEvent" function to replace official code by google that uses gtag function, for example:
gtag("event", "add_to_cart", {
  currency: "USD",
  value: 30.03,
  items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 10.01,
      quantity: 3
    }
  ]
});

